# java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, database, sqlite, forceclose

I designed an app and on click in image view and show image in new activity if back app force close.
I add list view code and database code if need new activity code say.
list view code:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class sharedlist extends ListActivity{

    private String[] items;
    private database db;

    private Typeface nazanin;
    private Typeface homa;

    private SharedPreferences sp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sharedlist);

        db=new database(this);
        db.open();

        items=new String[db.count("content")];

        nazanin=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Font/nazanin.ttf");
        homa=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Font/homa.ttf");
        sp=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("setting", 0);

        setListAdapter(new AAD());



    }









    class AAD extends ArrayAdapter{

        public AAD() {
            super(sharedlist.this,R.layout.row,items);
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            LayoutInflater in=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=in.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
            final String li=db.Display_shared(position,0);
            TextView username=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_username);
            TextView maintext=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_maintext);

            username.setText(db.Display_shared(position, 1).toString());
            maintext.setText(db.Display_shared(position, 2).toString());
            ImageView image=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_image);
            image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //new imageview("link",li).execute();

                Intent ed=new Intent(sharedlist.this,showImage.class);
                //new imageview("link",li).execute();
                ed.putExtra("postid",li);
                startActivity(ed);
                }
            });

            if(sp.getString("font", "homa").equals("nazanin")){


                maintext.setTypeface(nazanin);


            }else if(sp.getString("font", "homa").equals("homa")){

                maintext.setTypeface(homa);

            }


            if(sp.getString("size", "k").equals("k")){

                maintext.setTextSize(18);

            }else if(sp.getString("size", "k").equals("b")){

                maintext.setTextSize(25);

            }






            return (row);


        }






    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

and database :

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public final String path="data/data/packagename/databases/";
    public final String Name="database";
    public SQLiteDatabase mydb;

    private final Context mycontext;

    public database(Context context) {
        super(context, "database", null, 1);
        mycontext=context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

    }


    public void useable(){

        boolean checkdb=checkdb();

        if(checkdb){

        }else{

            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try{
            copydatabase();
            }catch(IOException e){


            }

        }



    }

    public void open(){

        mydb=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path+Name, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }

    public void close(){
        mydb.close();
    }

    public boolean checkdb(){

        SQLiteDatabase db=null;
        try{    
        db=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path+Name, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {

        }
        return db !=null ? true:false ;

    }

    public void copydatabase() throws IOException{
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(path+Name);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        InputStream myInput = mycontext.getAssets().open(Name);
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myInput.close();
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
    }



    public String Display(int row,int fild){
        Cursor cu= mydb.query("content", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        cu.moveToPosition(row);
        String name=cu.getString(fild);
        return name;
    }

    public Integer count(String table){
        Cursor cu= mydb.query(table, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        int s=cu.getCount();
        return s;
    }

    public void insert(String id,String user,String matn){

        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put("ID", id);
        cv.put("username", user);
        cv.put("matn", matn);
        mydb.insert("content", "ID", cv);


    }


    public String Display_shared(int row,int fild){
        Cursor cu= mydb.rawQuery("select * from content order by ID DESC",null);
        cu.moveToPosition(row);
        String name=cu.getString(fild);
        return name;
    }


}
```

log chat :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: data/data/package name/databases/database
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQOUp.png

Comment: cheak if appropriatr close method is called after db operations

Comment: show your error log. logcat maybe

Comment: Uncomment `db.close();` line in `onPause()` method. because every time whenever your activity goes into that states your database closed and whenever your activity start it enable to close your database because its already opened.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

> final String li=db.Display_shared(position,0);

line causing issue because database `open` method called in `onCreate` method before setting Adapter for ListView and `open` method called again in `getView` method without closing previous connection which is opened in onCreate method.

if you are getting data from database according to position then open/close connection in `getView` method instead of `onCreate` method

or you can also get all data from table using one query and store in any data-container like `ArrayList, Map,...` instead of querying database many times.